# Packr windows exe not working

Tags: windows64, packr

Downloaded the packr from https://github.com/libgdx/packr & 
Packr json is

```
{
"platform": "windows64",
"jdk": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_72",
"executable": "myapp",
"classpath": [
    "input/test-hello.jar"
],
"mainclass": "Main",
"vmargs": [
   "Xmx1G"
],
"minimizejre": "soft",
"output": "out-windows64",
"verbose": true
```

}
test-hello.jar has Main.class which simply writes "Hello" on System.out. 
There is no error reported while packaging the exe. However, when I run the exe, there is no output on the console. Is there anything in the json that I am missing? Does anyone have a simple working example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the path to the main class, for example

```
"mainclass": "com.example.Main",
```